# How many neutrinos would it take to accelerate a 75kg human?

Tags: acceleration, neutrinos

Assume that you have somehow creates a neutrino emitter that does not release any heat or light–just a lot of neutrinos.

You weigh 75kg, and step right into the flow of the emitter.

**How many neutrinos hitting you per second would it take to cause significant acceleration?**

Comment: Rather than being accelerated, as you turn up the neutron flow the first thing that's likely to happen is you'll die of radiation poisoning - any neutrinos that transfer momentum will do so by knocking electrons out, i.e. ionizing in the same way that gamma radiation does.

Comment: This question is just wrong on so many levels. What is "significant acceleration"? Why do we have to break the laws of thermodynamics and quantum physics to accommodate its premise? Why does a human have a mass of exactly 75kg?

Comment: An absolutely absurd number. Keep in mind that it would take about a light-year of lead to stop a neutrino. I quote from [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/neutrino3.html), "*Griffiths makes the statement "a neutrino of moderate energy could easily penetrate a thousand light-years(!) of lead."*"

Comment: [Relevant what-if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/), though it doesn't provide sufficient hard numbers to answer this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on various things: the energy $E$ of each neutrino, how likely each of them is to interact with a particle in your body (expressed as a cross-section $\sigma$, which depends on $E$), and how large an acceleration $a$ you consider "significant". Further let $m$ be your mass, $75\;\rm kg$.

I've pilfered some rough numbers from [here](https://www.quora.com/Radiation-Biophysics/How-much-neutrino-radiation-would-it-take-to-kill-a-human), namely $E=10\;\rm MeV$, $\sigma= 10^{-40}\;{\rm cm}^2$. According to that source the neutrinos will mainly interact with free protons (that is, hydrogen nuclei).

For a rough estimate, let's assume that you're made entirely of water, which is $\frac19$ hydrogen by mass. So you contain $\frac{N_A}9 m $ hydrogens, giving a total neutrino cross-section of $\frac{N_A}9 m \sigma$.

Suppose your frontal area is $A$; then the number of neutrinos that need to pass *through* you for one of them to *hit* will be $\frac9{N_A} \frac A{m\sigma}$.

How many neutrino needs to hit? They're near enough massless that each of them has an impulse of $E/c$, and the total impulse we need to impart over the time $t$ is $mat$. So we need $\frac{matc}E$ *hitting* neutrinos in each time period $t$.

The total required flux of hitting and non-hitting neutrinos is
$$ \frac 9{N_A} \frac{A}{m\sigma} \frac{mac}E = \frac 9{N_A} \frac{Aac}{\sigma E} $$

(Note that your mass actually cancels out. The heavier you are, the more hits will be necessary to accelerate you, but proportionally more hits will also happen for the same flux).

---

But what is this actually, in numbers? Let's write all of our constants in SI units and stick to orders of magnitude so we can take the leading factor of $9$ to be $10$. Then we might take

$$\begin{align}
N_A &= 10^{24} \;\text{per gram} = 10^{27}\;{\rm kg}^{-1}\\
A &= 1\;{\rm m}^2 \\
a &= 1\;{\rm m/s}^2 \\
c &= 10^8\;{\rm m/s} \\
\sigma &= 10^{-40}\;{\rm cm}^2 = 10^{-44}\;{\rm m}^2 \\
E &= 10\;{\rm MeV} \approx 10^{-12}\;{\rm J} \end{align} $$
Then it's just a matter of adding and subtracting exponents and we get
$$ \frac{10^{1+0+0+8}}{10^{27-44-12}} = 10^{38} $$
neutrinos per second.

Which is, as already noted in comments, vastly more than the dose that will kill you instantly due to radiation effects anyway.

---

Your neutrino beam will contain about $10^{26}\;\rm W$ of power, which is about the same as the total energy output of the Sun. If you power the neutrino gun by total energy conversion, you'll need to provide something like 10 million tons of of matter/antimatter fuel per second.

The recoil force will be about $10^{18}\;\rm N$, which is so absurdly large that I can't even find anything funny to compare to.

Comment: Yes, I know $N_A$ is supposed to be dimensionless, but remembering it as "baryons per gram" seems to be easier for back-of-the-envelope calculations.

Comment: *"According to that source the neutrinos will generally interact only with free protons (that is, hydrogen nuclei)."* That's true strong. They'll be a non-trivial number of interaction with electrons too. But you don't make an order of magnitude error that way so I'll not quibble.